# Problem downloading miktex

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I am going to download miktex for windowns 10 with 64 bit from the website: https://miktex.org/download

I have chosen all downloads and then net installer with 64 bit, once I click download, then the following error comes:

The connection has timed out

The server at ftp.funet.fi is taking too long to respond.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Can somebody kindly help to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Si vous êtes français, téléchargez-le depuis le mirroir d'Albi *(If you are French, download it from the Albi mirror:)* : [ctan.mines-albi.fr](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/windows/miktex/setup/windows-x64/)

Comment: No, I am not French. Please help me solving the above issue. Thanks.

Comment: Try this mirror http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/CTAN/systems/windows/miktex/setup/windows-x64/

Comment: Thanks. But the website I mentioned woked fine before. Suddenly the above error occur came. I want a solution to the above problem. Kindly help.

Comment: Maybe the web site is for now  being on maintenance.

Comment: I can't remotely fix a site that doesn't belong to me.  Contact its administrator, only he can do something. You can download from a MikTeX mirror, it's the easiest solution

Comment: that is clearly a network problem at that site or your machine , so nothing that we can fix here and not really related to tex.